# Change the value of synced textarea with keyup event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to change `ik` into `b` each time but it changes only once. I tried lot of methods to change it dynamically but I couldn't. Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {          
        var text1 = $("#ta_1").val();      
        var text2 = text1.replace("ik", "b");      
        $("#ta_2").val(text2);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta_1"   rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2"   rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `replaceAll` in javascript, you have to use `regular expression` with `global flag` for doing that.

So write your code like below,

```
var text2 = text1.replace(/ik/g,"b");
```

And your full code would be,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {          
        var text = $(this).val().replace(/ik/g,"b");
        $("#ta_2").val(text);
   });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xehyekas/)

Comment: @pinug Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that you want to replace all instances of `ik` in the `textarea`, then you could use a Regular Expression with the `g` global flag set. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {       
        var text1 = $("#ta_1").val();      
        var text2 = text1.replace(/ik/g, 'b');      
        $("#ta_2").val(text2);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
```

Comment: Exactly sorry for my english :) Thanks a lot sir